Hidden Markov Model with Multiple Agents
Consider this problem where a machine can be in either of two states (bad or good) and depending on the state with some probabilities (p_1 and p_2) it may produce good products (with probabilities 1-p_1 and 1-p_2 it may produce bad products). With a certain probability p it may switch from a good state to a bad state and if in a bad state, it will remain there. We can't see the state of the machine but we observe the products and can estimate what state the machine is in. We can understand when a switch in the states of the machine happens using a forward algorithm. My question is what if we have 100 machines and a more complicated markov chain for the states (assume three states)? Is it possible to estimate the percentage of machines in each state based on the products they produce over time?

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

You started setting up a model with two states, but then all of a sudden you want to assume three states?  Please tell us about the one you want. What are the switching probabilities for the three states?  What are their probabilities of producing good or bad products?  Are the $100$ machines independent?

Hello @RobertIsrael, thank you for your comment. The Markov chain of my interest is a three state model where there is a probability of moving from the first state to the second state and then backwards to the first state and a probability of moving from the second state to the third state and backwards to the second state (so there will be a total of four possible transitions 1->2 ,2->1, 2->3, and 3->2). This is the Markov chain I am thinking about but I have little knowledge about hidden markov models and I am just trying to understand what happens when we have more that one machine.

And the 100 machines are independent of each other.

And what about the products?  In each time period the machine produces either a good product or a bad product, with given probabilities $p_1, p_2, p_3$ of producing a good product?

Hello @RobertIsrael, For the case mentioned here, yes that is correct. I have emailed you a detailed description of the actual problem I am specifically interested in (the problem mentioned here is slightly different). I would highly appreciate any help that you could provide regarding that. Thank you.

EDIT: The author clarified that they are interested in the situation where only the aggregate number of good products at each time is known (rather than the output of each individual machine). This answer does not address that case, and assumes that a separate time series is available for each machine.
You can run a state decoding algorithm (e.g., Viterbi or forward-backward) separately on each machine, if they are independent of each other. You can also decide which of the parameters are shared between machines and which are not. For example, if you have $M$ machines, consider the following scenarios:

All machines have the same success probabilities $p_1$ and $p_2$ in the two states, and the same transition probabilities between the states (stored as a 2-by-2 transition matrix $\Gamma$). Probably reasonable if the machines have the same configurations.

All machines have the same probabilities $p_1$ and $p_2$, but different transition probabilities. This model would require machine-specific transition matrices $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2, \dots, \Gamma_M$. This might be useful if some machines spend more time in the "bad" state than others.

All machines have the same transition probabilities, but they have different success probabilities $(p_{11}, p_{21}), \dots, (p_{1M}, p_{2M})$. This represents the case where the "bad" state doesn't correspond to exactly the same behaviour for the different machines.


You could even have both transition matrices and success probabilities be machine-dependent, at which point you would be using a different hidden Markov model for each machine.
Let's say that you have $M$ time series of length $n$, where $z_{ij}$ is the $j$-th observation for the $i$-th machine ($z_{ij}$ is either "good product" or "bad product"). The most common state decoding algorithms take an inputs a time series of observations, and model parameters. So, for each machine $m = 1, 2, \dots, M$, you can run the decoding algorithm on the corresponding observations $(z_{m1}, z_{m2}, \dots, z_{mn})$, given the corresponding (possibly machine-dependent) parameters $\Gamma_m$ and $(p_{1m}, p_{2m})$.
References on state decoding:

Rabiner, L. R. (1989). A tutorial on hidden Markov models and selected applications in speech recognition. Proceedings of the IEEE, 77(2), 257-286. See "Solution to Problem 2" section.

Zucchini, W., MacDonald, I. L., & Langrock, R. (2017). Hidden Markov Models for Time Series: An Introduction Using R. Second Edition. CRC Press. See Section 5.4.



Hello @théo-michelot , Thank you for your response to the question. However there is a problem and that is I can only see the observations for the total system, it is unclear which machine they come from. Can you provide some guidance regarding this situation. I would appreciate your help.

Okay, I see, that seems like a more difficult problem. The state space is potentially very large (many possible combinations of good/bad machines out of 100), so I wonder if one approach would be to use a state-space model based on Gaussian approximations of the distributions involved.
